# Arzela-Ascoli, plain equicontinuity suffices?

Tags: equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

I would like to understand a bit better the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Statement_and_first_consequences)

> Consider a sequence of real-valued continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n ∈\mathbb{N}}$ defined on a closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$ of the
> real line. If this sequence is uniformly bounded and uniformly
> equicontinuous, then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k ∈\mathbb{N}}$ that converges uniformly.

More specifically I was curious to know if instead of requiring uniform equicontinuity we could just require equicontinuity. It seems to me that using the compactness of $[a,b]$ and the plain equicontinuity we get uniform equicontinuity anyways no?

Comment: That is correct; the proof is the same as ordinary Heine-Cantor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the domain is compact metric (like $[a,b]$) these notions are equivalent; for a proof e.g. see the note [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/23.pdf). It's the difference between EQ1 and EQ2 there.

Comment: Just a follow up question. In generalisation of Arzela-Ascoli one often asks that the the set of functions $F$ we consider are equicontinuous and pointwise precompact, i.e. $\{f(a) : f\in F\}$ has compact closure $\forall a$ but then I don't understand why in the basic form of the theorem we ask for uniform boundedness. Indeed, it seems to me that if we had $\{|f_n(a)| : n\in\mathbb{N}\}\le M_a \forall a$ would also be fine no?